# Combining networks in SPICE - Iteration

Tags: spice, pspice

Let us say you have two networks, A and B, that depend on each other. The voltages in circuit A influences the resistances in circuit B, and vice versa. The goal is to find a steady-state solution of the two networks. Assume that there is some equilibrium condition that can be used to check whether you have reached the final state.

The procedure is as follows
1) Solve circuit A with some initial conditions.
2) Insert the results from 1) into circuit B and solve.
3) Check equilibrium condition. If equilibrium has been reached you stop here, if not; go  back to point 1) but insert the results from 2).

I am using OrCAD PSpice now, and I don't see any straightforward way to implement this procedure. One solution would be to use voltage-controlled resistors and connect the networks in a huge complex network, but this seems very cumbersome and I run into convergence problems.

My question is: Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps by programming it in Python/Spice. Or is there an easy way to do this in OrCAD? Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like something the SPICE solver does automatically. Have you tried placing the two networks, interconnected, straight into the schematic? `.OP` should do what you want, then maybe you can save the `.op` and use it for future simulations. I don't know if PSpice has it, but I know LTspice does.

Comment: Hi, and thank you, no I haven't tried that. What do you mean by interconnected? In practice all the resistances in circuit B depend on voltages in circuit A and vice versa. Is it easy then to change the convergence conditions?

Comment: If the resistances depend on voltages, then you may have to impose a few `ic`, to help the solver. But I'd say it's worth a try, there will not be any smoke.

Comment: Can you show a snippet, or a very simple example on this dependency? Any simple circuit that behaves the way you intend to. It might help.

Comment: One (usually last resort) trick for large circuits is to start a transient simulation with only DC sources and skip the initial DC/OP simulation. E.g add UIC to the .tran analysis statement. Then save the final operating point.